# How to generate n samples of r observations in R

Tags: r, regression

This is the question I have been given in my stats homework:

[image: picture]

I have been asked to first generate 500 samples of size 20 observations before I can continue on with the other parts of the question.  However I am not good with R so I do not know how to do this.  I have been told to use a loop to generate the 500 samples, but how can I do this?

Comment: Here are a few examples of such code on our site: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=rnorm. Because there are so many of them, consider refining the search.  Here's one that focuses on generating random numbers in a standard regression context: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=rnorm%20regression%20-logistic%20-forest.